# first time sql database creation table name area shows in red

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hi I am creating a sql database for the first time hand writing the code, I am using phpMyAdmin to create the databases. I am creating tables called Subject, Level, Area and principle; they are all going to be linked with each other using foreign keys but I noticed when typing in the table name Area it shows in red any ideas or a simple explanation.

My code so far is:

```
   CREATE TABLE subject (
subject_id VARCHAR (50) PRIMARY KEY,
description VARCHAR (200),
FOREIGN KEY (level_id) REFERENCES level(level_id),
FOREIGN KEY (area_id) REFERENCES area(area_id),
FOREIGN KEY (principle_id) REFERENCES principle(principle_id)
) Engine = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO subject (subject_id, description)VALUES 
('Mathematics', 'this is the maths description'),
('English', 'this is the  description'),
('Science', 'this is the science description'),
('Computing', 'this is the computing description'),
('Design and Technology', 'this is the Design and technology description'),
('Art', 'this is the Art description');

CREATE TABLE level (
level_id VARCHAR (50) PRIMARY KEY,
description VARCHAR (200),
FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subject(subject_id),
FOREIGN KEY (area_id) REFERENCES area(area_id),
FOREIGN KEY (principle_id) REFERENCES principle(principle_id)
) Engine = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO level (level_id, description)VALUES 
('Key Stage 1', 'this is year 1 - 2 in school'),
('Key Stage 2', 'this is year 3 - 6 in school'),
('Key Stage 3', 'this is year 7 - 9 in school'),
('Key Stage 4', 'this is year 10 - 11 in school'),
('Key Stage 5', 'this is year 12 - 13 in school');

CREATE TABLE area (
area_id VARCHAR (50) PRIMARY KEY,
description VARCHAR (200),
FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subject(subject_id),
FOREIGN KEY (level_id) REFERENCES level(level_id),
FOREIGN KEY (principle_id) REFERENCES principle(principle_id)
) Engine = InnoDB;
```

The code line this happens on is

```
     FOREIGN KEY (area_id) REFERENCES area(area_id),
```

is it because the word represents something else and you cannot create a table called area or will it be fine ?

Comment: FOREIGN KEY ('area_id') REFERENCES 'area' ('area_id')

Comment: @RaghunandanKrishnamurthy I cannot see a difference if it is the spaces then it still shows that one word in red.

Comment: Is `area` table already created? Or you're trying to create `subjects` table first?

Comment: Please desc area; desc level;

Comment: @Sasha I am running one sql query to create all of the tables at once so this code above will be used to create the others as well.

Comment: Phpmyadmin is sometime overzealous with reserved words.

Comment: @RaghunandanKrishnamurthy I don't understand what you mean. could you explain please I am new to sql and databases.

Comment: But the code above doesn't contain `CREATE TABLE area (...)`. Where is it?

Comment: @Mihai Does this mean that it would be ok if I ran this query or would i have to change the words.

Comment: Im not sure,just get a better client.Also area is not defined in your table definition,how can you use it as a foreign key?

Comment: @Sasha I have added my full code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL thinks you are trying to reference the [Polygon Area Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/polygon-property-functions.html#function_area) - you're best best is to quote 'area' as detailed in the first comment by @Rag.

Comment: so the line of code should be: `FOREIGN KEY (area_id) REFERENCES 'area'(area_id),` will this effect anything else or do I need to add the '' marks to the other table names ?

Comment: when I add the '' the table name now turns green would this be a problem or is this correct

Comment: Any time you reference Area you would need to quote it to convey that you mean your 'Area' table not the Polygon Area function. A better approach is generally to avoid using names of existing MySQL objects / routines. For example 'tblArea'.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I have changed it from area to section and that seems to work Ok.